# Terminator doesn't open new window

Tags: gnome-terminator

[Terminator](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/terminator) 0.95 (running on Debian stable under Gnome) has shortcuts for "Spawn a new Terminator process" and "Create a new window". However, when I set them (to several different options, in case there is a conflict) and try to use, instead of a new window I get a lightbulb in the header of the current tab. There are no error messages in the terminal I am running Terminator from, but looking again at keybindings, the shortcuts become disabled. Trying to use the shortcut without closing the preferences window didn't work either.

What does it mean and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please [edit] your question and include i) the version of terminator; ii) your desktop environment; iii) clarify which terminator you're using, unfortunately, there are two terminal emulators with the same name ([1](http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) and [2](https://code.google.com/p/jessies/)); iv) run terminator from another terminal and check if there are any error messages when you try to use your shortcuts.

Comment: @terdon I've edited it, but looking at the link you provided and the config file gave me the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Heh, cool, thanks for posting the answer. It'd be great if you could remember to come back and accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at `~/.config/terminator/config`, for some reason it was using `<Primary>` instead of `<Ctrl>`. After deleting the keybindings section, the original shortcut `Shift+Ctrl+I` for new window works.

Comment: removed(back up) the config file, then the terminator would start successfully. And you will get a fresh config file:)